# Showing Message for loading WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, message

I have a WPF application that connects and disconnects to WiFi.
 It takes around 2 seconds to complete the process. During that time, I want to show a simple **waiting message** on the top of my current window "Connecting.." or "Disconnecting...", which closes as soon is the process is complete.

What should I use?

`MessageBox` is not working because a) it has a button, and b) I can't just close it at my own will through code (I think).

Comment: You disable the form, show another smaller form, and then when the WiFi is connected you can hide the smaller form and enable the form again.

Comment: @ViggoLundén The current form would hide once disabled, right? I want it to be present behind the message form, like in the case of message box.

Comment: See my answer below, that should work.

Comment: I recommend to use a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Wi-Fi starts to connect, use:

```
MyWindow popup = new MyWindow();
popup.ShowDialog();
```

Where `MyWindow` is a small form containing information.

And when the Wi-Fi is connected, use:

```
popup.Close();
```

`ShowDialog()` prevents user interaction with the parent form.

Comment: How can I pass the text to this new window from the parent's code behind?

Comment: `MyWindow` would be a normal form, which you would design as any other form. Make a constructor and call it with information text from the parent: `MyWindow("Connecting to Wi-Fi...")` or something like that.

Comment: The parent window apparently stops doing its process (connecting) until the popup is closed.

Comment: `ShowDialog()` opens a modal window. You can use `Show()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the long-running task that takes two seconds to complete on a background thread and show and close the window on the dispatcher thread, e.g.:

```
Window window = new Window()
{
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
    Content = new TextBlock { Text = "working..." }
};
Task.Run(() =>
{
    //do something that might take a while here...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}).ContinueWith(task => window.Close(),
    CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
window.ShowDialog(); //Call .Show() instead if you don't want to block here until the task has finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing I use a busy  "throbber" or "spinner" which is shown in a panel on top of the window. That just animates to show something is going on.
I bind the visibility of that to an "IsBusy" property in my window's viewmodel.
In a base viewmodel that inherits from, because this is a common requirement.

When I set Isbusy true, the spinner appears and animates.

When I set it False, the spinner disappears.

I also have an area where I show messages. These are animated so they appear and then fade out after a few seconds.

It's a bit much code to paste into a SO answer, but there's working code uses this approach here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Entity-Framework-MVVM-78cdc204

Throbber is the usercontrol to look at.

This usually goes in a panel covers where the user would edit stuff - so they can't change data as it's being updated.

I also use IsBusy in the CanExecute predicate of commands to disable buttons etc as processing is done. Because notification isn't necessarilly instant I check inside all commands and exit if IsBusy is true.  Commands set IsBusy true whilst they run.

For completeness and probably not directly relevant to Bella's question.

In some situations I want to just show the user that processing is happening but allow them to continue working. This happens a fair bit in the Map and Scenario editors of the game I'm working on. 
For example, when you mouse over a commander there's a Spatial A* best route calculation happens between a commander his subordinates that can take in the order of 1 to 12 seconds. I don't want to block the user but I want to show something is going on in this instance.

I have a second mechanism with a less intrusive throbber I use for this. That appears next to my user notification message.

Comment: agreed and I would add IsBusy is used to disable/dim the main app portion.

Comment: Ah... I should have covered that. Thanks for the reminder.